# creating fixed size queue for c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I develop code for creating fixed size queue in c++. I am struck in how to extend std::queue to have this functionality.  I looked at other similar SO questions, but they don't give a clear example on how to do this.Is there any examples I can refer to  on how to do this. Thanks

```
template<typename T>
class fixed_size_queue: public std::queue<T>
{
    public:
            fixed_size_queue(unsigned int size);    


};

void fixed_size_queue::fixed_size_queue(unsigned int size)
{
    this->size()= size;


}
```

Comment: SO isn't for resource requests. Did you have a specific error or problem in your implementation that you wanted to ask about?

Comment: You can't modify the size like this. Create your own class with a size property, handle your own pushes and count them, throw some exception if your queue is full.

Comment: Thanks, is there any example you can point me to.

Comment: Why? Why not just use a standard `queue`? Is the 'fixed' size to be an upper bound on the size? Or a lower bound? Or both?

Comment: In the std::queue, there is litereally no limit to the amount of elements you can push into it. But for my application, I need to have a fixed size queue. If more elements are pushed, the new element being pushed needs to be dropped.

Comment: Silently dropped? I thought that you might mean, for example, that an error should be thrown if it grows too big

Comment: That largely depends on your requirements. For my specific application,  I need the new element to be dropped unless a space become free (through a dequeue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't extend standard containers since it's very unsafe. The better solution is to create your own class and use the `std::queue` as a class member along with any internal restrictions required for your class.

Comment: Good point. Somebody might override `queue::push` but forget to override `queue::emplace`, which would therefore allow a 'backdoor' via which the queue could grow too big

Comment: If I get that right, I need to create a class member and override most of the the methods in std::queue, based on my requirement.

Comment: You'll want to create a new class, add your std::queue as a member of that class, have your own functions(push(), empty(), etc..) wrap your requirements in those functions. Does this make more sense, or would you like me to edit in an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can extend queues to have fixed size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

template< typename T > 
class FixedQueue: public std::queue< T > { 
public:
    Processor( int size )
        : S( size )
    {   
        current = 0;
    }   

    int push( T value )
    {   
        if (is_full()) {
            std::cout << "Is full" << std::endl;
            return -1; 
        }   
        else {
            std::queue< T >::push( value );
            ++current;
        }   
    }

    void pop() 
    {   
        if (!std::queue< T >::empty()) {
            std::queue< T>::pop();
            --current;
        }   
    }

private:
    inline bool is_full() {
        return !( current < S );
    }   

    const int S;
    int current;
};
```